# How to split single column data in two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
userid   checkTime              type
------------------------------------
10       2014-01-11 10:41:37    IN
10       2014-01-11 18:12:37    OUT
```

How to change this data to something like this, in SQL Server

```
userid   time in               timeOut
--------------------------------------------------
10       2014-01-11 10:41:37   2014-01-11 18:12:37
```

Comment: I know this is not what you are asking, but, would it not make more sense to have the following fields? `userid`, `checkInTime` and `checkOutTime` once they check in set the `checkInTime` to the current time and then have the default for `checkOutTime` as "Still Checked In". When they check out, update the `checkOutTime` with the time they checked out.  Just my thought.

Comment: how do you specify that second row is to be concated? Are rows come in pairs of ids?, is there any other rule yoou decide the concat?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.userid,
       x.[time in],
       x.[time out]
FROM
    (SELECT userid, 
            checkTime AS 'time in',
            NULL AS 'time out'
     FROM table
     WHERE type = 'IN'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT userid, 
            NULL AS 'time in',
            checkTime AS 'time out'
     FROM table
     WHERE type = 'OUT') AS x
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pivot:

```
SELECT userid, [IN], [OUT]
FROM yourtable
PIVOT
(
MIN(checkTime)
FOR TYPE IN([IN],[OUT])
) AS P
```